# Sum of array is negative and trying to reach constant, but it re-sizes with a positive integer

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

My title is awful.

I'm trying to make an array of a haphazard number of members, randomly assigned negative values. I want the sum of this array to fix itself to a specified constant. But, when it does, every once in a while I get a positive number as the last element. I'd rather just add that value to the previous element and delete the positive element. I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

**Note**: *this is an attempt at refactoring this one method to work on both positive and negative totals*

```
I have x Chutes = -150 and y Ladders = 100. 
x + y should = Total, unless I resize the array. 
sum (Ladders + Chutes) = -50
```

This is the entire module before the function, it will print on to a sheet to see the results.

To avoid reading the superfluous stuff, it generates a number and splits it to two groups, then passes those groups with the constants to the last function. **The last function is where I'm having the problem** - there are positive elements when my boolean specifying negative is `True`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const TOTAL_LADDER As Long = 100
Public Const TOTAL_CHUTE As Long = -150

Public Sub ChutesAndLadders()
    'testing only
    Range("A:C").ClearContents

    Dim allChutesLadders As Long
    Dim numberOfChutes As Long
    Dim numberOfLadders As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim chutes As Variant
    Dim ladders As Variant

    allChutesLadders = TotalObjects
    numberOfChutes = Int(allChutesLadders * Rnd + 1)
    If numberOfChutes = allChutesLadders Then numberOfChutes = allChutesLadders - 1
    If numberOfChutes = 1 Or numberOfChutes = 2 Then numberOfChutes = 3
    numberOfLadders = allChutesLadders - numberOfChutes

    If numberOfLadders = 1 Or numberOfLadders = 2 Then
        numberOfLadders = 3
        numberOfChutes = allChutesLadders - numberOfLadders
    End If

    Cells(1, 5) = "Total"
    Cells(1, 6) = "Chutes"
    Cells(1, 7) = "Ladders"
    Cells(2, 5) = allChutesLadders
    Cells(2, 6) = numberOfChutes
    Cells(2, 7) = numberOfLadders
    Cells(1, 1) = "Chutes"
    Cells(1, 2) = "Ladders"

    chutes = ChuteLadderLengths(numberOfChutes, TOTAL_CHUTE, True)

        For i = 1 To UBound(chutes)
            Cells(i + 1, 1) = chutes(i)
        Next i


    ladders = ChuteLadderLengths(numberOfLadders, TOTAL_LADDER, False)

        For i = 1 To UBound(ladders)
            Cells(i + 1, 2) = ladders(i)
        Next i

End Sub

Private Function TotalObjects() As Long
    Dim totalCount As Long
    totalCount = Int((17 - 9 + 1) * Rnd + 9)
    TotalObjects = totalCount
End Function
```

And here is that function

```
Private Function ChuteLadderLengths(ByVal countChutesLadders As Long, ByVal totalChutesLadders As Long, ByVal isChute As Boolean) As Variant
    Dim index As Long
    Dim sumOfChutesLadders As Double
    Dim differenceFromTarget As Long
    Dim makeChutesNegative As Long
    makeChutesNegative = 1
    If isChute Then makeChutesNegative = -1

    Dim myChutesLadders() As Double
    ReDim myChutesLadders(1 To countChutesLadders)


    For index = 1 To countChutesLadders
        myChutesLadders(index) = Rnd()
    Next index

    sumOfChutesLadders = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(myChutesLadders)

    For index = 1 To countChutesLadders
        myChutesLadders(index) = Int(myChutesLadders(index) / sumOfChutesLadders * totalChutesLadders)

        If myChutesLadders(index) = 0 Then myChutesLadders(index) = makeChutesNegative * 2

    Next index

    sumOfChutesLadders = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(myChutesLadders)


    differenceFromTarget = totalChutesLadders - sumOfChutesLadders
    If differenceFromTarget <> 0 Then

        myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) = myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) + differenceFromTarget

    End If


    For index = 1 To countChutesLadders - 1
        If Abs(myChutesLadders(index)) >= 98 Then
            myChutesLadders(index) = myChutesLadders(index) - (makeChutesNegative * 50)
            myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) = myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) + (makeChutesNegative * 50)
        End If
    Next
    'why can chutes end with a positive number?
    If isChute And myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) >= 0 Then
        myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders - 1) = myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders - 1) + myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders)
        countChutesLadders = countChutesLadders - 1
        ReDim Preserve myChutesLadders(1 To countChutesLadders)
    End If
    'Something can go wrong here
    If Abs(myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders)) >= 98 Then
        ReDim Preserve myChutesLadders(1 To countChutesLadders + 1)
        myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) / 2, 0)
        myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) / 2, 0)

    End If

'HOW DO I HAVE POSITIVE CHUTES HERE?
If isChute And myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) >= 0 Then MsgBox "positive chute"

     ChuteLadderLengths = myChutesLadders()

End Function
```

---

In this part

```
        For index = 1 To countChutesLadders - 1
            If Abs(myChutesLadders(index)) >= 98 Then
                myChutesLadders(index) = myChutesLadders(index) - (makeChutesNegative * 50)
                myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) = myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) + (makeChutesNegative * 50)
            End If
        Next
```

- Line 3 is `-` and line 4 is `+` which allows positive chutes
- If Line 3 is `+` and line 4 is `+` I still allow a positive chute and my total chutes can be `-250` instead of `-150`
- If Line 3 is `+` and line 4 is `-` I still allow positive chute
- If Line 3 is `-` and line 4 is `-` I still allow positive chute

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably confident that this is what is causing your problem:

```
      'This next array value will always be positive... it goes up by 50 every loop
        myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) = myChutesLadders(countChutesLadders) + (makeChutesNegative * 50)
```

Comment: The `makeChutesNegative` = `-1` so it *should* be decreasing when `isChute` is True.

Comment: If that's the case, then the line above is *adding* instead of subtracting: `myChutesLadders(index) = myChutesLadders(index) - (makeChutesNegative * 50)`

Comment: Right. So after the `if abs(mychutesladder(index))>=98` I have the first line and the second line. If the first is `-` and the second is `+` I get a positive chute. With `+` then `+` I still get positive chutes and the total chutes can be `-250` instead of `-150`. If I do `+` and then `-` I can get a positive chute. If I do `-` and `-` then I can still get a positive chute. +1 for the help, but it still doesn't work.